# Adding a link to a Kendo UI gridview for each item with item ID in href

Tags: linq, gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am developing in Razor MVC .NET.  I have an entity framework where my data is coming back nicely, i.e., I have this set up, for example:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Web.Models
{
    public class Training
    {
        public int Id {get; set;}
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string editLink {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MyProject.Entities;
using MyProject.Data;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using MyProject.Web.Models;

namespace MyProject.Web.Controllers
{
    public class TrainingController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            using (var db = new MyDb(false))
            {
                var data = db.Training.Select(d => new TrainingModel
                {
                    Id = d.Id,
                    Name = d.Name
                    // I want to do this, here:
                    // editLink = "<a href=Training.cshtml?mode=edit&Id=" + d.Id + " target=_blank>Edit Training</a>";
                }).ToDataSourceResult(request);
                return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

The view isn't important - a standard Kendo UI-based gridview that calls the "Read" routine above.  I've also altered the code a little just to give a basic idea of what I'm doing.

What I want to do is to concatenate a hyperlink with each ID, and display it on a column  in the gridview for each item, so a user can click that link and off they go to another page where they can edit their item.  I can't do the line I've commented out, above, because "Id" is an int in the database, and I need to have the HTML in a string or maybe an object?  Either way, they don't mix in the formats they're in right now, and LINQ doesn't seem to let you alter it on-the-fly.

- I tried `SqlFunctions.ConvertString` and it does not even recognize `SqlFunctions` as a type.
- I would use the built-in editing, but there is data from other database tables I will need to show on the other page that go along with the ID, and Kendo controls only let you focus on one table at a time.

So, in short, how do I insert a link into a gridview column using this Select statement, or can I?  Or is there another way to edit the Json data before it is returned?  Or are people doing it some other way completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would send the url over as a string such as `Url.Action()` and then in the client use use a `Column.ClientTemplate()` on your grid column with an anchor. This will work if you are using Mvc wrapper for the grid.

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var db = new MyDb(false))
        {
            var data = db.Training.Select(d => new TrainingModel
            {
                Id = d.Id,
                Name = d.Name
                // I want to do this, here:
                editLink = "Training.cshtml?mode=edit&Id=" + d.Id.ToString();
            }).ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
     }
```

Grid Configuration:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyClass.MyCollection>()
    .Name("myGrid")        
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(t => t.editLink).Title("Action").ClientTemplate("<a href='${editLink}' target=_blank>Edit Training</a>");  
    //OR       
        columns.Bound(t => t.id).Title("Action").ClientTemplate("<a href='Training.cshtml?mode=edit&Id=${id}' target=_blank>Edit Training</a>");  


    })
    ....
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but `d.Id.ToString()` doesn't work.  "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression" is the error.  Linq doesn't allow the .ToString().

Comment: Your 2nd part, the Grid Configuration works though!  You were right, I could just use the id one in the 2nd columns.Bound statement.  I just added `columns.Bound(p => p.Id).Title("Action").ClientTemplate("<a href='Training.cshtml?mode=edit&Id=${id}' target=_blank>Edit Training</a>");` and it worked perfectly!  Thanks!